# I am trying to get and store life google map location in firebase using geoflutterfire but facing a version issues

Tags: flutter, firebase

The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.0.

```
Because geoflutterfire >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-nullsafety.3 depends on cloud_firestore ^1.0.0 and geoflutterfire
  >=3.0.0-nullsafety.3 <3.0.1 depends on cloud_firestore ^2.0.0, geoflutterfire >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.1 requires cloud_firestore  ^1.0.0 or ^2.0.0.
```

```yaml
  firebase_core: ^2.15.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.7
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.9.0
  provider: ^6.0.5
  get_it: ^7.6.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.0
  geolocator: ^10.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`geoflutterfire`](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire) is not really maintained anymore. The last release was 21 months ago. So it is using an old version of `cloud_firestore` (`< 3.0.0`).

And you are trying to use the version `^4.9.1` which is too high.

You have several things you can do:

### 1. Use [`geoflutterfire_plus`](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire_plus)

It seems like it is a fork of `geoflutterfire` that is up to date (The last release was 47 days ago).

### 2. Downgrade your package versions.

You can try to downgrade the versions in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
cloud_firestore: ^2.0.0
```

You might have to downgrade other packages (like `firebase_core` or `firebase_messaging`) to make it work.

But if you do this, and `geoflutterfire` doesn't release new versions, you'll be stuck with `cloud_firestore: ^2.0.0` forever

### 3. Use [`dependency_overrides`](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides):

```yaml
dependencies:
  firebase_core: ^2.15.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.7
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.9.0
  provider: ^6.0.5
  get_it: ^7.6.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.0
  geolocator: ^10.1.0

dependency_overrides:
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.1
```

This will force to use `cloud_firestore: ^4.9.1` in your application (and packages likes `geoflutterfire`). But this can lead to some issues:

> Using a dependency override involves some risk. For example, using an override to specify a version outside the range that the package claims to support, or using an override to specify a local copy of a package that has unexpected behaviors, may break your application.

Comment: which of these is the best option? Because i need the application in production early next year

Comment: The 1st option seems like a better option long term to me. But that is only my opinion